# iterator as function input in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have problem in the following simple code:

```
  void foo (vector<int>:: iterator it, vector<int> n)
  {
       vector<int>:: iterator it2 = it +1;
       while (it2!=n.end())
       {
           cout<<*it2<<endl;
           it2++;
       }
  }
  main()
  {
        vector<int> m{1,2,3,4};
        vector<int>:: iterator it = m.begin();
        foo (it, m);
  }
```

I expected to have 2, 3 and 4 in the Terminal, but I got some stupid results in output. Is it basically possible to use iterators as functions' input? What is wrong in this piece of code? and How can I make it correct?

Comment: `n` is a copy of `m`, its iterators are not related to `it`

Comment: Since you pass m as value the address space of n is different than the one from your original m because n is a copy of m.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You pass `vector<int> n` as a copy. Thus your `it2` points to a different vector (the one that was created in `main`). Your check `it2!=n.end()` is invalid since `it2` is an iterator to another vector.

Passing `n` by reference is one solution. Other would be passing the end iterator instead of vector.

To pass your vector as a const reference:

```
void foo (vector<int>:: iterator it, const vector<int>& n)
```

To pass an end iterator:

```
void foo (vector<int>::iterator it, vector<int>::iterator end)
{
 ...
     while ( it2 != end )
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems: one is that you're passing a copy of your vector argument, as Satus and yeputons already pointed out.

The second problem is that the first line of `foo` is already illegal if the argument is empty. That is, even the trivial fix

```
void foo (vector<int>:: iterator it, vector<int> &n)
{
   vector<int>:: iterator it2 = it +1;
```

is wrong if `it == n.end()`.

The correct design is the one used for all the library algorithms, and for the same reason: that it can correctly express empty ranges.

```
void foo (vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end)
{
   if (begin == end) return;
   for (auto i = begin; i != end; ++i)
   {
       cout<<*i<<endl;
   }
}
```

Your weird skipping-the-first-element design makes it a bit ugly still, a nicer approach is to have some utility help skip the first element, and then use copy:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator try_advance(Iterator i, int count, Iterator end)
{
  for (; count-- > 0 && i != end; ++i)
    ;
  return i;
}


void foo (vector<int>::iterator begin, vector<int>::iterator end)
{
   // skip first element of a non-empty range
   // leave an empty range un-damaged
   begin = try_advance(begin, 1, end);
   std::copy(begin, end, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, '\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. But mind that iterators are tied to their container.

Second parameter of your function is copy-constructed from argument, i.e. `vector<int> n` is a *copy* of `vector<int> m` defined in `main`. So, your function tries to compare iterator with another iterator (`.end()`) from a different container. You'd better pass both begin/end iteratos instead of container.